# Event call on TextBox lostFocus within a list view

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates

I have a ListView bind to List, one of the column of the listview has cellTemplate with dataTemplate containing a textBox. i want an event to be called when the textBox loses Focus, it compares the text box's previous value and new value (if User has changed[image]), if the new value is greator, it shows a warning,

Answer (score 0):

Look at ExceptionValidationRule

[ExceptionValidationRule Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.exceptionvalidationrule.aspx)

[Customize Data Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx)